# How to line tables horizontally in HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Basically, my code automatically generates a ton of tables (not a fixed number, depending on input), and the layout by default is just vertically down, one after another.

I would like to line the tables horizontally to fill up the page's width before moving on to the next row of tables.
For illustration purposes, it currently looks something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvMoM.png

I want it to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k568a.png

I am a beginner creating a react app. Any help would be appreciated!

So far, the closest I've gotten is using "float: left" but the tables align in a weird slanted way, and all my buttons float all the way to the right.

Edit: The relevant snippet of my code is below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v65Zc.png
I tried copy and pasting my code directly but it turned out weird so while i figure that out, pls refer to this screenshot!

Edit2: My code now looks like this, I simply added  around my table :)

```
<div class="table">
    <table>
        <tr><th>Combination {index + 1}:</th></tr>
        { combi.map((slot, id) => (
        <div className="slotInfo">
            <tr>
                <td>{GetAllCombisInfo().filter(combi => combi.length > 0)[index][id].code} {GetAllCombisInfo().filter(combi => combi.length > 0)[index][id].type} {slot.slot_name}:</td>
                <td>{slot.day} from {slot.startTime} to {slot.endTime}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    ))
    }
    </table>
</div>
```

And added this to my css file

```
.table {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

My website still looks the same, perhaps I'm missing something important or made a mistake. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you provide the code that will make more sense

Comment: Either way you can use `display: flex` and `flex-wrap:wrap` to the parent div or table whatever you have

Comment: Please provide us the code you have written

Comment: Thanks everyone! I have edited my post to include my code, I hope that'll help you help me haha display: flex and flex-wrap: wrap has not worked so far. Pls advice :)

Comment: Also, whoever that downvoted my question, I would like to inform you that I just joined stack overflow yesterday to ask this question, I don't know what information needs to be provided for you to help me. Give people a break...

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: flex property of CSS  to the parent tag of you table.

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
 <table>
  <tr>
     <td>Column 1</td>
     <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Column 1</td>
     <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <table>
  <tr>
     <td>Column 1</td>
     <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Column 1</td>
     <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 /* List of table */
</div>
```

Comment: Put this markup in a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and include the closing `</div>` and I'll upvote this answer

Comment: I have made changes as you say

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <h4 style="text-align:center;">
    /* List of table */
  </h4>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
     <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
      <tr>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 1</td>
         <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 3</td>
         <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
      <tr>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 1</td>
         <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 3</td>
         <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
      <tr>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 1</td>
         <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 3</td>
         <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
     <tr>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 1</td>
         <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 3</td>
         <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
     <tr>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 1</td>
         <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 3</td>
         <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
     <tr>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 1</td>
         <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 3</td>
         <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
     <tr>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 1</td>
         <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cell 3</td>
         <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope it will give you an understanding. Thanks

Comment: Hello @amateurcoder, welcome to stackoverflow. As you provided screenshot of your code. I don't see you have wrapped your table inside a div. Can you try wrapping the table inside a div after the download button div

Comment: Hello @sayan0020! Thanks for the advice, I have wrapped the table inside a div and added .table {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
} to my index.css, and everything still looks the same :( I'll update my code as of right now just in case I missed out something...

Comment: OK. Now can you inspect and see that style properties are effecting. It is not getting overwritten by any other class/style properties. If it is overwritten by any other class, then can you add  **.table { display: flex !important; flex-wrap: wrap !important; }** . Then check.

Comment: if it is still not working then can you give us [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  which we can render on our system and see where is the issue.

Comment: I just realised a very stupid mistake I made... I have been styling around the wrong div (div around each table content instead of div around the whole code block generating tables). Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Yes, I've shared the code also in that manner, inside the div, all the tables are there. BTW, good you figured it out.

Comment: I tried to but need 15 reputations. Will do so the second I get there thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code snippet below:

```
 <html>
      <title>Tables</title>
      <body>
      <h4 style="text-align:center;">
        /* List of table */
      </h4>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
         <table border="1" border-style: dotted solid double dashed style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
          <tr>
             <td>Column 1</td>
             <td>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 1</td>
             <td>Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 3</td>
             <td>Cell 4</td>
          </tr>
         </table>
           <table border="1" border-style: dotted solid double dashed style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
          <tr>
             <td>Column 1</td>
             <td>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 1</td>
             <td>Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 3</td>
             <td>Cell 4</td>
          </tr>
         </table>   <table border="1" border-style: dotted solid double dashed style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
          <tr>
             <td>Column 1</td>
             <td>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 1</td>
             <td>Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 3</td>
             <td>Cell 4</td>
          </tr>
         </table>   <table border="1" border-style: dotted solid double dashed style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
          <tr>
             <td>Column 1</td>
             <td>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 1</td>
             <td>Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 3</td>
             <td>Cell 4</td>
          </tr>
         </table>   <table border="1" border-style: dotted solid double dashed style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px;">
          <tr>
             <td>Column 1</td>
             <td>Column 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 1</td>
             <td>Cell 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Cell 3</td>
             <td>Cell 4</td>
          </tr>
         </table>
       
         
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I hope this helps you